# Composite function rates of change

Tags: word-problem

The area of a circle is $A(r)=\pi r^2$. The radius of a circular oil spill is increasing at a speed of $1/2$ m per second.

1. Express the radius as a function of time.
2. Find the composite function $A(t)$
3. When is the area $100\pi$m^2?

Comment: Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: Answering these questions.